# Django - QuerySet is not iterable in permissions.py

Tags: python, django

New to Django and Django Rest here.

I have the following structure :

```
class MyUsers(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

class roles(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    label = models.CharField(max_length=80)

class user_roles(models.Model):
    id_user = models.ForeignKey(MyUsers,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    id_role = models.ForeignKey(roles,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I'm trying to create a custom permission, to allow users with a specific role to access some endpoints.

```
class IsAuthenticatedAndLeader(BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        id_role=models.roles_users.objects.filter(id_user=request.user.id).values_list('id_role',flat=True)
        if "Leader" in models.roles.objects.filter(id=id_role).values_list('label',flat=True):
            return request.user and request.user.is_authenticated    
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
            return True
```

When I try to access to the endpoint, I have the following error:

```
TypeError: argument of type 'QuerySet' is not iterable
```

However if I try in views.py something simple like the following it works :

```
if "Leader" in models.roles.objects.filter(id=3).values_list('label',flat=True):
    print("Yes")
```

So I'm not sure why I'm getting this error when trying to apply it to permissions.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem its

```py
id_role=models.roles_users.objects.filter(id_user=request.user.id).values_list('id_role',flat=True)
if "Leader" in models.roles.objects.filter(id=id_role).values_list('label',flat=True):
```

`id_role` is a list and you can get roles `where id=(ids....)`
then it not works, try with:

```py
if "Leader" in models.roles.objects.filter(id__in=id_role).values_list('label',flat=True):
```